# Game Start Scene

Tags: game-engine

I am making a game with several scenes.  How do I tell blender which scene to start the game in?  (For some reason, it won't start the internal player in the pause or intro scene).

Comment: For one, you could just move things over to different layers and have the game start on the first scene. Seeing as how you have an intro screen, it looks like you have got the buttons all worked out. Can *you* teach *me* how to do that?

Comment: doesn't just being in that scene that you want as the start make it the start scene?

Comment: Inside blender it does.  I'm not sure about when I package it however.  I could test it myself, but I was just wondering if there was a way to guarantee that one would start before another.

Comment: hmmm.... i would just make a simple scene(s) to test which it default loads into. if you don't want to i will when i get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "Save As Game Engine Runtime" Extension/Add-on to export your game to an .exe/.app the program should start on the scene you had open/active in your blender program when you exported it.

So before exporting your game:

- Select the scene you would like start your program in.
- File > Save (Save your blend file.)
- File > Export > Save As Game Engine Runtime

I tested this on Windows 10 it should be the same on all systems but just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a logic brick "always" and connect it to a "scene" actuator to set the scene.